# How to find unresolved variables in Angular 2 templates

Tags: angular, templates, webstorm, lint

I have a project with a generated client. That means, models are autogenerated from a JSON file. When a property name in the backend has changed and I check a template with a changed property in it (e.g. `user.name` became `user.firstName` in the model for `User`), I see that it has green underlining in WebStorm, but the page opens and it just doesn't get displayed. But if I didn't open the template, I wouldn't recognize the problem.

So is there either some setting for WebStorm or for Lint to complain more when the HTML files' properties are recognized as "unresolved variables"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In webstorm, if you perform a code analysis, do you see the unresolved variable in the Inspection Results?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/analyzing-inspection-results.html

Otherwise if you are using tslint, codelyzer is an extension for tslint that has various rules specific to angular.

I think the specific codelyzer rule, `no-access-missing-member`, is what you would be looking for. If you set that up, then you could run tslint in your console and get a list of errors.

http://codelyzer.com/

Comment: This didn't help me, it didn't report any problem. Except there exists maybe a setting somewhere that lint excludes html completely? Or does that not exist?

Comment: What does your tslint.json file look like? Are you referencing your templates or are they inline?

Comment: the templates are referenced and in separate files, not inline. And I didn't find any rule in my tslint.json excluding any file type (or especially html)

Comment: The web storm code analysis works. But do I really need to run it additionally each time?

Answer (score 0):

... meanwhile (Angular v5), there was a lint rule existing for that, which is now replaced by the Angular compiler complaining (AOT) on production mode.